# How can I perform calculations on values which are spread across multiple rows with repeating identifiers and combie them into one?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am fairly new to pandas and these are the details of my problem,
The dataset is created from a postgres db table using query:
`SELECT e_code, e_name, status,date FROM {table_name} WHERE month=(%s) AND year=(%s) AND status !='P' AND status !='OFF' GROUP BY ("e_code","status","e_name","date") ORDER BY("e_code") ;`

Which results in following data frame:

```
   e_code  e_name  date  status
26    40        A 2023-04-21      H
24    40        A 2023-04-07      H
25    40        A 2023-04-14      H
28    42        B 2023-04-14      H
29    42        B 2023-04-21      H
..    ...      ...        ...     ...
79    80        S 2023-04-21      H
16    50        T 2023-04-10      1AL
80    50        T 2023-04-07      H
81    50        T 2023-04-14      H
82    50        T 2023-04-21      H
```

I am trying to calculate how many leaves are taken by that employee based on the status of rows of that employee,
for eg. if status=="H" it should increment holiday_count by 1 , if status == *AL then it should increment other_leave_count by * and store the date in a column on which the leave was taken, which I need to perform for all employees present in the dataset.

After this,I need to subtract the total no of holidays taken by that employee from a total value  (both holiday_count and other_leave_count are treated separately here)and print the whole dataset to a file.

What can I do to achieve this?

as this problem is complex for me at the moment, I am counting both holiday and other leaves but only calculating remaining holidays at the moment. So far, I have tried:

1. append new columns holiday_date other_leave_date and perform mask to identify on which date which type of leave was taken, and then count the leave for that row which I then subtract from total.

```
temp_df["holiday_date"]= ""
temp_df["casual_date"]=""
temp_df["holiday_count"]=0
temp_df["other_leave_count"]=0

temp_df["holiday_date"].mask(temp_df["status"]=="H", temp_df["date"], inplace=True)

# set count of holidays
temp_df.loc[temp_df["holiday_date"]!=0,"holiday_count"]=1

# set count of other leaves
temp_df.loc[temp_df["casual_date"]!=0,"other_leave_count"]=1


#final calculation

temp_df["holiday_leaves_taken"] = None
temp_df["holiday_leaves_taken"] = temp_df["total_no_holiday_leaves"]-temp_df["holiday_count"]
```

Which results in wrong final values for no of leaves taken, as both holiday and other_leave_count are treated on each row basis.

2. I have tried using apply to create and check rows for status "H" and status !="H", which contributes to same output as above.
3. I have tried using df.iterrows() to iterate through rows and  find value in status column and perform calculations that way, but I am unable to differentiate between rows as to know if they are record of same or different employees.

Expected Output:
|Name of the employee |Period From |To|total_holiday_leaves|holiday_leave_count|available_holiday_leaves|Period From |To|Total leaves|other_leave_count|available_other_leaves|
|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|
|x|07.04.2023        14.04.2023   21.04.2023|07.04.2023        14.04.2023   21.04.2023|14|3|11|NA|NA|4|0|4|

Comment: Can you provide another example for one employee and the expected result, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom aggregation function:

```
def custom_agg(group):
    holiday_count = (group['status'] == 'H').sum()
    other_leave_count = (group['status'].str.isnumeric()).sum()
    total_leaves = holiday_count + other_leave_count

    # Subtract the total leaves from some predefined value
    total_value = 20  # Replace this with your actual total value
    remaining_leaves = total_value - total_leaves

    return pd.Series({
        'Holiday_Count': holiday_count,
        'Other_Leave_Count': other_leave_count,
        'Remaining_Leaves': remaining_leaves
    })
```

then,

```
result_df = df.groupby('e_code').apply(custom_agg).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you. 
could you please explain how the custom aggregation function works?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Calculate leave's count
df['Holiday_Count'] = (df['status'] == 'H').astype(int)
df['Other_Leave_Count'] = (df['status'].str.isnumeric()).astype(int)
df['Total_Leaves'] = df['Holiday_Count'] + df['Other_Leave_Count']

# Replace 'total_value' with actual total leaves
total_value = 20
df['Remaining_Leaves'] = total_value - df['Total_Leaves']

# Group by 'e_code' and sum the counts for each employee
result_df = df.groupby('e_code').agg({
    'Holiday_Count': 'sum',
    'Other_Leave_Count': 'sum',
    'Remaining_Leaves': 'first'  # Assuming remaining leaves are the same for each employee
}).reset_index()
```